# Express: match route for language code in url

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I'm trying to capture an optional `:lang?` param of two charachters for this routes:

```
/             // lang: undefined
/en           // lang: en
/projects     // lang: undefined
/en/projects  // lang: en
```

This is my try:

```
router.get('/:lang([a-z]{2})?*', function(req, res, next) {

}
```

But for `/projects` it sets a `:lang?` parameter as `pr`.

How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To beat this issue you can try to use the next pattern:

```
/:lang([a-z]{2})?/:rest(*)?
```

Here another optional param `rest` is introduced to capture such a trailing.

You can check live examples:

- https://obsidian-oboe.glitch.me/
- https://obsidian-oboe.glitch.me/en
- https://obsidian-oboe.glitch.me/projects
- https://obsidian-oboe.glitch.me/en/projects

Comment: @Nikita actually you can give that additional param an arbitrary name, not necessary `rest`